# How to "save" (core-data) for "master/parent" entity while in "detail" entity view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

In my app I have a model as shown:

[image: Core-data model for App showing both entities, properties and relationships.]

A Playlist can have none or multiple Items. On creation of a Playlist in the master view, it is stored with default data and the view segues to the Item List [detail] view where items can be added/deleted. This works fine.

However, while in the detail (item list) view there is a property (targetEndTime) that I wish to set that should be stored in the referenced Playlist object. I want this to store implicitly while on the detail view and not when I return to the Master View.

How do I achieve this?

If it is best practice to refactor out the core-data out of the two view controllers, how would this be done, and how would I save to the particular object reference?

Many thanks for your help and input.

***UPDATE***
TargetEndTime is a set property, from which the start time is calculated. It is a 'backtimer' - I want to know the time to start the playlist set so that it ends at the targetEndTime. So, when targetEndTime is set, I want to store this in the parent entity.

how in code might I achieve this? I am passing the playlist:

```
self.playlistViewController = (BXPlaylistViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;              
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];                  
Playlist *playlist = nil;         
playlist = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];            
self.playlistViewController.playlist = playlist;
```

Comment: The target end time changes according to the number (and duration) of items added, correct?

Comment: no, it is a set property, from which the start time is calculated. It is a 'backtimer' - I want to know the time to start the playlist set so that it ends at the targetEndTime. So, when targetEndTime is set, I want to store this in the parent entity.

Comment: As you can see from your data model, an `Item` has an inverse relationship to its `Playlist` too. You can therefore access an `Item`'s playlist and modify its `targetEndTime`.

Comment: Where / how in code might I achieve this? I am passing the playlist:

`self.playlistViewController = (BXPlaylistViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        
        Playlist *playlist = nil;
        playlist = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.playlistViewController.playlist = playlist;`

Comment: I think you're not much experienced with CoreData. You should really start with something simpler. Explaining how you you should go about achieving is out of my abilities.

Answer (score 1):

As described by the comments you can access the playlist of an item directly via its relationship.

so assuming you keep a reference to the list in its detail view.

e.g `@property Item *focusedItem`

```
-(void)updateTargetEndTime:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval {

    Playlist *playlist = [self.focusedItem valueForKey:@"playlist"];

    [playlist setValue:@(timeInterval) forKey:@"targetEndTime"];

}
```

Thats the most primitive version , but as you advance with coredata you'll want to use tools like [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) or simply Xcode

[image]

to create shim classes for your managed objects which will allow  you to express it like this.

```
-(void)updateTargetEndTime:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval {

    item.playlist.targetEndTimeValue = timeInterval;

}
```

Comment: No need for mogenerator. Xcode does this as well (and maybe better).